# Magento 2 API: How do I list products as a customer or anonymous user

Tags: api, magento, magento2

I'm build a mobile app that uses magento 2 REST API. So in this I can add products to cart and even complete an order. But it seems to me that I cant list products or categories as a customer or guest user. As an admin I can do that. This is the error that I get

```
{
  "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
  "parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Catalog::categories"
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can use the "/V1/products" API as a customer or guest?

I guess the only other option I have is to build my own customer API that lists products/categories for anonymous users.

Answer (score 2):

there is a specific settings to allow anonymous user access to hidden rest API endpoints:

Configuration > Services > Magento Web API > Web API Security. Then select Yes from the Allow Anonymous Guest Access menu.

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/anonymous-api-security.html

Comment: Is there any way to only make one endpoint available? I.E: GET /V1/products